# Import table in SQLite (Android)

Tags: android, sqlite

In my android project, I have a **dynamically created** SQLite Database which has multiple tables that save **user-generated** values. However, I also want a table in there which is **pre-filled**.

***CONDITIONS:***
-> These tables **need to be in the same database**, since I want to join them (And as far as I know, you can't crossjoin tables from different databases. At least that's not possible in MySQL)
-> I want the database to be **dynamically created by the application**, since I want to use the advantages of `SQLiteOpenHelper.onUpgrade()`.

***IDEAS:***
The static table will only contain about 100 rows, which is why I considered putting all rows directly into the code (either directly as `INSERT INTO` statements or in an ArrayList, for example). Once the database is created, the whole content from the ArrayList is copied into the table.
Problem: Then I have the same text twice on the user's phone - once as code and once in the database. 100 rows wouldn't really need much space; but as a good coder I still try to avoid this.

The second idea is very similar. On other threads, I have read that tables of SQLite can be saved as .csv files. They could be parsed by my android application and put into the table.
That would also result in having the data twice on the phone.

---

Is there a possibility which I am missing? I've made very much searches on google today but never found solutions to import tables into an Android SQLite database (only importing full databases).

Comment: SQLite has an ATTACH command: https://www.sqlite.org/lang_attach.html. However, unless you are making separate databases (e.g. for different users) and don't want static data in all of them, I think it's far easier to just have the static data live somewhere (either in your java or in some other asset) until the time you insert it.

Comment: Do you have experience with the ATTACH command (in android)? Because after reading the documentation a bit, it sounds like two databases are combined during runtime (in android that would mean the databases are combined everytime the app is started?) I feel like that is not a good performant solution.

Comment: `having the data twice on the phone.` Yes, if you INSERT the rows. Not if you REPLACE the rows.

Comment: What do you mean by replace? What am I supposed to replace?

Comment: @TobiasBaumeister Combined might not be the most appropriate term, but they are attached until you issue a `DETACH` command. I'm not a fan of using the `ATTACH` command on Android for a number of reasons (such as that it disables WAL for the attacher and there isn't a way to enable it again without closing and reopening, or that it can fail spectacularly if either DB has open transactions, depending on which DB and which threads those transactions are on). I say put the static stuff in java or in an asset and insert it when you create your DB.

Comment: Thanks for the input :) I'm surprised that there seems to be no solid solution for that. Luckily my table will be less than a MB, so having it twice on the phone won't hurt anyone

Comment: Maybe, you didn't read my comment. **REPLACE** will UPDATE the row if existing and INSERT it if existing. Use `REPLACE INTO` instead of `INSERT INTO` - Refer to the official SQLite documentation.

Comment: But I don't understand how that would make sense in relation to my question? My concern is where/how to save the data before the SQLite database is even created on the user's device after the app installation. I don't have any data in the database yet, so I can't replace anything.

Comment: Did you mention importing CSV files then having duplicate data? Or did I dream of it? By the way, if you don't insert @Frank... at the beginning of your message, I won't be notified. I don't need to, since you are the OP.

Comment: @FrankN.Stein: Yes, I'm saying that I will have duplicate data because I will have the CSV file on the user's device, but also the table in my programmatically generated database which COPIES the data from the CSV file into a new generated table. I don't know any way how to include the CSV file in my database without copying its content (which is what the title of this thread implies)

Comment: How do you **copy** the rows? By using INSERT. I just told you to use REPLACE instead of INSERT.

Comment: @FrankN.Stein: I'm inserting them into an EMPTY programmatically generated data table. How would replace make a difference when there's nothing to be replaced?

Comment: Then how can the data be duplicated? If it's EMPTY, then the CSV data is copied 1 to 1. OR you are somehow repeating the INSERTS. In this case, using REPLACE will prevent duplicate entries.

Comment: @FrankN.Stein  Because it is copied from a `.csv` file (without database) into an empty table in a programmatically generated database. Then the user has the `.csv` file AND the data table on their device. Or do you know a way to MOVE the `.csv` file into the database without copying it value by value? Because that's what my main question is about.

Comment: @FrankN.Stein: My concern is not that the values are stored twice in the same table. My concern is that the values are stored twice on the device. Once as the `.csv` file, which is only used for the database creation, and once as the finished `data table`.

Comment: I can't get you... you can delete the CSV file, after the insertion into the db.

Comment: @Frank.N.Stein: It's not possible to delete asset files which were downloaded with the application. Additionally, I would like to keep the opportunity of resetting/rebuilding the database for whatever reason, without making the user re-download my application again.

Comment: So... keep the data duplicated. I was to suggest to use a SQLite db instead of the csv, but the data would be duplicated as well. There's no solution. Other than keeping the original data on a server and simply get the data into your db as needed.